# How to find out which records have been filtered out by Queryable attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an asp.net web api controller for which I have enabled odata query options. The controller is as follows:

```
[Queryable(PageSize = 10)]
public IQueryable<MyDTO> Get(string Id)
{
  //some code here
}
```

As obvious from the `Queryable` attribute, this controller always returns 10 records at a time if there are more than 10 `MyDTO's`.

How can I find out which 10 records have been returned or which records have been filtered out by odata query option?

Answer (score 0):

All pageSize does is do a [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx) on the queryable your action returned after the incoming $filter, $orderby, $skip, $top have been applied first. If you want to post-process the items that you return after the query is applied, you can take [`ODataQueryOptions<MyDTO>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj890615%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) as input and manually apply it on the `IQueryable`

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to share an example of usage of `ODataQueryOptions`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public IQueryable<MyDTO> Get(string Id, ODataQueryOptions<MyDTO> queryOptions)
    {
        IQueryable<MyDTO> allMyDTOs = GetMyDTOs(Id);
        ODataQuerySettings settings = new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = 10 };
        IQueryable<MyDTO> appliedMyDTOs = queryOptions.ApplyTo(allMyDTOs, settings) as IQueryable<MyDTO>;
        return appliedMyDTOs;
    }
```

Here are some samples.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options