# Building future-proof OData service with Entity Framework context for both desktop and asp

Tags: wpf, wcf, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, odata

We are developing a WCF REST service which will be consumed by a desktop WPF application and will also be a source of data for the ASP MVC4 website.

So far I've run into countless technical issues and most importantly I am worried about the future of the Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider. (Please check blog comments [here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/data-driver/2013/10/wcf-data-services-supports-entity-framework-6.aspx)).

The issues include:

- <strike>There is no easy way (without using DTO) to add properties on the service entities which will be passed through OData but won't be stored in the database</strike> Actually there is an easy way:

  ```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
       modelBuilder.ComplexType<CustomType>();
  }
  ```
- There is no easy way (without parsing XML or using DTO) to store properties on client entities without them being sent to the service (v5.6.0). The "hard" way is to hook into RequestPipeline and ResponsePipeline:

  ```
  Configurations.ResponsePipeline.OnEntryEnded(OnReadingEntry);
  Configurations.RequestPipeline.OnEntryEnding(OnWritingEntry);
  ```
- using DTO is cumbersome to say at least, automapper helps with retrieving of IQueryable results but updating entities requires full implementation of IUpdateable, which actually works on DTO but is required to update entities so implementation of it is very tricky if even possible (I searched for existing solutions and these mostly cover in memory data source so I implemented a working solution but without links, I can dig it from source control if anybody is interested). Tested on v5.6.0.
- Client entity containing dynamic field will crash when retrieved from a service (checked on 5.6.1)
- accessing DbContext from EntityFrameworkDataServiceProvider requires a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953784/entity-framework-6-data-context-from-wcf-data-service)

This package has not been updated for almost half a year and this fact itself is very worrying.

My question is what Microsoft or open source alternatives to Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider link between EF context and a client are suitable to replace this supposedly dead library? The critical requirement for such a link would be to have a tracking client-side context and entity framework 5 or 6 compatible service.

Is Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData a good solution also for desktop applications?

Are there any other Microsoft or open source projects have similar capabilities?

Comment: Have you checked out Breeze? http://www.breezejs.com/

Comment: You should look at http://servicestack.net/

Comment: It looks like Breeze is a JavaScript library so it's suitable only for web. We mainly need C# client consuming the service.

Comment: @EwaldStieger ServiceStack doesn't offer any support for OData. OData (or Google's GData) defines a query mechanism and schema. It's not just a matter of transferring DTOs

Comment: Here is a blog about WCF DataService and Webapi OData: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/27/future-direction-of-wcf-data-services.aspx . It may help you make a decision.

Answer (score 2):

For WCFDS update, you can refer to [Future Direction of WCF DS service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/27/future-direction-of-wcf-data-services.aspx).

In the issues you listed, I am sure that issue 1 can be easily resolved in web api by tag [IgnoreDataMember], [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847362/how-to-find-out-which-records-have-been-filtered-out-by-queryable-attribute/22471748#22471748).

For Issue 2 and 4, one suggestion is you can add a data layer in client, which can handle extra data model and dynamic field

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of thoughts...REST is not the same as OData...so your question is confusing. If you meant WCF Data Services, then definitely go with the new WebApi. As Maya's link shows, The WCF DS team announced they are basically done.

However, your client is usually agnostic of what technology you are using for odata and its data layer...its a disconnected architecture. So if you have a mapping impedence on the server side, that is one issue, but which client is consuming the odata ought to be irrelevant. But likely I did not understand your stated problem correctly...Do you mean that you own both the client and server and want to share the entity class definitions? If you are that tightly coupled, you can add service resources customized for the client, and others customized for your MVC app.

For some practical workaround, WCF DS offers query interceptors, that let you manipulate outgoing data. The new WebApi is basically works from controllers and gives you full control over intercepting the requests and manipulating what needs to be done with the data.

Finally, just a suggestion for your desktop client...Lightswitch works wonders with oData...point and click...it generates your proxy and client model on the fly and gives you huge control over the client and what it does with the responses from the server.